# ClassName has not been declared compiler error, with an inherited cyclic dependence after using pragma once

Tags: c++, class, g++

I have three classes: Person, Family and Graph. There is a cyclic dependence between Person and Family and I forward declared Person within Family. They are both included within Graph. When compiling, I am getting a g++ error that states (for every instance of Graph::* within graph.cpp) 
" 'Graph' does not name a type " and all data members within graph.h are saying they aren't declared in this scope. (They are all public)

The problem is fixing the compiler error and understanding how to handle this cyclic inherited dependency so that the Graph class is compiled.

I have tried forward declaring Person and Family within Graph as well as using #pragma once.

Family.h

```
#pragma once
//...

class Family{
   int foo;
};
```

Family.cpp

```
#include "person.h"
//...
void Family::functions(){}
```

Person.h

```
#pragma once
#include "family.h"
//...
class Person{
   int foo;
};
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "family.h"
void Person::functions(){}
```

Graph.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H
#include "person.h"
#include "family.h"

class Graph{
   Person * people[NUM_PEOPLE];
   Family * families[NUM_FAMILY];
};
```

Graph.cpp

```
//...
class Family;
//...
Graph::Graph(){}
//Here Graph does not name a type

void Graph::GraphFunc1(int someParams){
//Here Graph does not name a type

   //implementation...
   //Lets say somewhere in this function we use people[] and families[]

   people[0] = something;
   families[1] = something;

   //Here families and people are not defined in this scope
   //Although they are declared PUBLICLY in Graph.h
}
```

I expect the array of object pointers people and families to be defined in the scope of graph.cpp since they are defined publicly in its header. Does this have anything to do with Graph not naming a type? FWIW, the 'Graph does not name a type' compiler error comes up before the others.

Comment: In graph.cpp `Graph` has not been defined. Post real code.

Comment: @PeteBecker Can you explain in more detail what else you wish for me to include in the graph.cpp code? The actual file itself is far too long for a question about dependency issues (imo)

Comment: Are you getting error even after including other header files to Graph.cpp?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that. I tried with #include family.h and #include person.h in graph.cpp and still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you include `Graph.h` too?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I didnt #include Graph.h as I thought it was implied inheritance from its own header. I just tried it though and got the same error

Comment: 1. You need to declare functions and constructors in `Graph` class under `public:` section as `Graph();` and `void GraphFunc1(int someParams);` 2. `GraphFunc1` should have some return type such as `void` and function implementation should also have it .`void Graph::GraphFunc1(int someParams){` 3. `people` and `families` declared inside `Graph` class and they are not public so I am not sure if you can access them outside the methods of `Graph` class.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya 1: I did that, thats what the ```//...``` means is that there are functions of the type: ```void Graph::GraphFunc1(int someParams)``` 2. Again, there are return types for all of my functions within graph, what I am providing here in the post is a shortened version so that it is more clear which classes depend on which and how I have set up my include statements. ```people``` and ```families``` are public, this is stated in the question.

Comment: You’re right to chop out distractions, but you have to leave enough so that people can compile your code and get the same error message. In the course of doing that careful chopping you might spot the problem yourself. Reducing a problem to the smallest code that shows the problem is a valuable skill.